# Is there an option to somehow display all nodes that that doesn't have a menu link?

Tags: nodes

As almost all users here know, you can set up a menu link to each node from the "Menu settings" tab in the node's edit form.

Is there an option to show all nodes that don't have a menu link?

I tried to create a view and use the filter criteria to achieve that, but no relevant filtering option appeared for me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to create a view and use the filter criteria to achieve that, but no relevant filtering option appeared for me there.

A workaround would be:

1) Add a Boolean type field to your content type.

2) Check-mark the field for all the nodes that have a menu link

3) Filter view by your boolean field. (where the boolean is false, unchecked, equal to 0)

[image]

**Bonus:** If you're using Drupal 7 you could use [Menu Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_rules) which lets you add the a condition

> Conditions:
>   - Node has menu entry - checks if the node has a menu link.

Therefore, you can use rules to automatilly check or uncheck your boolean field, that way you don't have to remember to check it or uncheck it, when you check or uncheck the menu link option.

> **Note:** As pointed out, if you have lots of menu link nodes, which would make ✓ check marking all their boolean field annoying and time
>   consuming, you can create a Rule Component that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) with the **Node has menu
>   entry condition** to check mark all of those nodes boolean fast.

**Bonus 2:** If you did Bonus 1, you can use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to hide your boolean field from the edit page.

Comment: Didn't know about "Menu rules", interesting! However what about "existing content" (before you'd implement as you suggested in your answer)? How about adding VBO for some type of one time only conversion, whereas you'd trigger a Rules Component (with a condition like NOT 'Node has menu entry') to update the existing content also?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks, forgot to take into account that.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens `with a condition like NOT 'Node has menu entry'` actually we don't need to. Because the boolean will be false by default. The nodes that need updating would be the menu link ones, where we checkmark the boolean (setting it to TRUE). Unless he has a ton of menu link nodes, no need to VBO.

Comment: actually I need to test my answer, to see if we need VBO or not.

Comment: yeah, no need to VBO unless you have a ton of menu link nodes, which need to be updated to (1 aka true aka be checkmarked).

Comment: Please do not add a "part 2" to this, the answer is already more than sufficient for the question that was asked, and will end up being another overblown, unreadable mess that we have to consider deleting if you keep editing and adding to it. We are not trying to write documentation here, or cover every possible eventuality that the OP doesn't mention, just to **answer the question that was asked** in a **brief** and **succinct** manner. The overblown "this covers every possibility ever, even if you didn't ask for it" answers are going to be clamped down on, they're poisonous to Q+A. Thanks!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If I could down vote your last comment, I would too. `trustworthy solution` is not the right description. If he tries my answer it will work. I think `not totally thorough` would be the better way to describe it. I agree with @Clive, it's not our duty to cover every possibility. It is actually the OPer's duty to tell us if he has lots of menu links or just a few. Since he did not tell us, common sense tells me to assume he has few menu links. If the OPer forgot to mention he has lots, he can always post a comment and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens In addition, remember that we are doing this on our free time. Being totally thorough can be time consuming. Time that we could be using for something else. The onus is on the OPer to make the question as specific as possible and not on the answerer. Although, a small note or comment talking about the possibility is always welcomed and fine in my books **:)**

Comment: @NoSssweat : ok, "fair" (further edited) answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to handle this would be to get all of the menu items, and the nodes associated to them.  Then perform a EntityFieldQuery on nodes.  Making sure that your query includes a 'NOT IN' condition, and use the ids from the nodes you discovered in the menu as the values.

This would return all nodes not in your menus.

Comment: Maybe use menu_tree_all_data() for get all menu items and filter the NIDs? 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x